# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initIssues'), but this is defined in issuesContext.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting error as the title suggests, undefined error. However I have already defined in ***issueContext.js*** and calling in **AllIssuesPage.js**.

[image]

This is the code page

[image]

```js
<!-- AllissuesPage -->

import React from "react";
import DataApi from "../data/DataAPI";
import CommentList from "./commentList";
import { IssueContext } from "./issuesContext.js";

export default class AllIssuesPage extends React.Component{
    static contextType = IssueContext;
    componentDidMount() {
        DataApi.getAllIssues()
            .then((data) => {
                this.context.initissues(data);
            });
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <h1>Issues list</h1>
                <CommentList />
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export const IssueContext = React.createContext();

export class IssueProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            issues: []
        }
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <IssueContext.Provider value={{
        ...this.state,
        initissues:( (issues) => this.setState({issues:issues})),

      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </IssueContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export const IssueConsumer = IssueContext.Consumer;
```

Comment: Please include the code, not just a photo :)

Comment: This photo contains code in a js format and from VS code which is a common platform for all. This will be better to identify the issue.

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13181643) explaining why is better to include the code and not a photo.

Comment: Okay, As per the demand I added code. Please provide the solution.

Comment: I am new to this environment. Extremely sorry if I hurt you. I will never do this again. Please..

Comment: Are you wrapping at some level your `AllIssuePage` with the `IssueProvider`? Asking cause if the `IssueProvider` is not rendered as parent of `AllIssuePage` at some level *(like your main app component for example)*, you will have no context to get in the children.

Comment: No, I am not wrapping AllIssuePage with the IssueProvider.

Comment: I would try wrapping all of your components that needs the shared context, with the context component (`IssueProvider`). (With only one `IssueProvider` a the end, not one for each component that needs it)